# How to implement a function for removing some attributes in Vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2, jsx, virtual-dom

Let's say we want to implement a `removeInlineStyle` function to receive a VNode(`foo = <Foo style="color: red" />`) and return a style-removed VNode.

Comment: we dont remove style like that. but you can define a style in Data model and by any condition you can apply or remove it. refer to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer @SaJed, but we don't want to modify the component's internal code, we want to implement it just like higher order components.